# Chess parity problem

Tags: chessboard

On an 8x8 chess board we place rooks so that the number of them is odd on each line  or collumn.
Show that the number of black squares that have rooks is even.

What I found:
Obviously, since the sum of all rooks is even, the numbers of black and white squares with rooks have the same parity.
Also since every line or column have even number of squares, the number of them with/ without rooks have the same parity so every arrangement generates another one.
This is basically the only relevant thing I have got. I still dont know how to get the parity

Comment: Oops, It's a duplicate

Comment: I lost the link but there is the same problem

Comment: Do you mean this one? [Semi-Ambiguous Combinatorics Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860768/semi-ambiguous-combinatorics-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that this is a duplicate and I am sorry
Here is the solution (I lost the stack exchange link) https://www.quora.com/If-every-row-and-column-on-a-chess-board-has-an-odd-number-of-pieces-on-it-how-can-I-prove-that-there-are-an-even-number-of-pieces-on-black-spots